# How do I prevent character from being printed twice inside for loop? c++

Tags: c++

This question *looks* similar to other questions (which I have checked.) However no question posed has the answer I'm looking for.

I am using C++ to write a program to check if a character out of a string is a vowel or a consonant and to use a counter loop to iterate over the string to produce the results. isalpha() is inside a bool function named 'isVowel' which only does 2 things. 1 It checks if the value checked is indeed a legal alphabet character. 2 It checks if the character is a vowel, if true, it returns true to main. I need to be pointed in the direction as to why my cout 'is vowel' is being printed twice below the original string in the for loop 'if (answer == true)' statement.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char word){
    if(isalpha(word)){
        if(word == 'a' || word == 'A')
        {
            return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}

int main ()
{   
    //Variables

    string choice;
    bool answer;

    //program starts here
    cout << setw(50) << "Vowels and Consonants" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> choice;

    //while loop gathering each letter of the word to test for vowels/consonants
    /*while((unsigned)index < choice.length())*/
    for (int index = 0;(unsigned) index < choice.length();){

        char letter = choice[index];
        answer = isVowel(choice[index]);
        cout << letter <<  endl;

        if(answer != false){
            cout << letter << " is a vowel" << endl;    
        }

        index++;
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Consider removing `cout << letter <<  endl;` because you also do `cout << letter << " is a vowel" << endl;` That's why you print the same letter twice. Btw, not only `a` is a vowel :P

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use the debugger `gdb`**. Your fix-my-code question is off-topic

Comment: DimChtz, Thanks for the idea however it only produces 'a' as the vowel I'm testing. I wanted to keep my original string there and produce the 'is a vowel' on the right side of the original string next to said vowel. Thank you.

Comment: `if(answer != false){` can be written simpler as `if(answer){`

Comment: You print it twice, so it gets printed twice. Count them `cout << letter` lines. It would be rather strange if it was printed three times...

Comment: Yeah since i'm indexing the location of the characters I want to test, it throws an error at me if I remove any cout  or rearrange them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change lines 36-40 with an expression like this: `cout << letter << ((answer != false) ? " is a vowel\n" : "\n");`

Comment: inside the question mark space is where I should place the variable that I am saying 'is a vowel' ?

Comment: Yeah, this is called ternary operator. After you declared "answer" you print letter and check if answer != false; if answer is true it prints "is a vowel\n" else it prints just a new line.

edit: It's like:
`if(answer != false) cout << "is a vowel\n";
else cout << "\n";`